# Funny Things Students say... on hold

Tags: discussion

I like the answers that have come in on this one. I think it could be valuable, though I don't know how to reword it. Just wanting to collect what made you laugh isn't a good enough criteria.

The third answer is less on-topic to my mind, perhaps because it is only a language issue, where the others are misunderstandings about math. Ahh, that's it! Being able to understand why students misunderstand is important for us (teachers). Thinking about it through humor can help us.

New title proposal: When student misunderstanding about learning math becomes humorous

But you all can do better than that.

Do you see the value in this?

Comment: (http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7458/funny-things-students-say-when-learning-mathematics)

Comment: Thanks, @ChrisCunningham.

Comment: On the one hand, I too liked some of the answers as they conveyed in a playful way some insight. On the other hand, I am worried it will be difficult to keep such a  question focused. If we try it might be better to start with a fresh post.

Comment: Actually I like the proposed title.

Answer (score 11):

I don't.

The original post was a mere collection of anecdotes that won't help educators anywhere and, to me, serves only to mock students. That is not the type of soft question I want in MESE. As such, I have downvoted and would have voted to close if it wasn't on hold.

Comment: I had not looked at it that way. But you certainly have a point that it might also be perceived this way.

Comment: I voted to close for these reasons as well.